# MonogDB resets the saved value automatically after some time

Tags: node.js, database, mongodb, authentication

I am using `node.js` to build a small game and to store states/token i am using online database `mongolab`. I generate the token with the following function:

```
UserSchema.methods.generateAuthToken = function() {
var user = this;
var access = "auth";
var token = jwt.sign({_id: user._id.toHexString, access}, "abc123").toString();

user.tokens = user.tokens.concat({access, token});
return user.save().then(() => {
    return token;
});
```

};

The `save` function is :

```
UserSchema.pre("save", function(next) {
    var user = this;
    console.log("Being saved");
    if (user.isModified("password")) {
        console.log("Being modified");
        bcrypt.genSalt(5, (err, saltvalue) => {
            bcrypt.hash(user.password, saltvalue, (err, hash) => {
                user.password = hash;
                next();
            });
        });
    } else {
        next();
    }
});
```

If i stay at a certain page for `sometime(delay)` then database resets the token to empty array.

However i  have inserted everywhere `console.logs` to see if the server is trying to reset the value but the database does it automatic. 
If someone has knowledge about this kind of error,then it will be of great help.